# How to use an arrayList to implement next() in Iterator

Tags: java, iterator, binary-search-tree, inorder

I am attempting to implement an iterator class for my binary search tree. (to be more precise, it is a KD-Tree, but I don't think that will change things much). I want the iterator to follow an in-order traversal of the tree. I have an arrayList which contains the leaf nodes in this "in-order" order, and I would like the iterator to iterate through these leaf nodes in this order. How can I use this arrayList to implement next() method?

I have tried creating an int field called index in the Iterator class. Then my next() method would increment the index by 1 and return arrayList.get(index). However, this didn't seem to work.

Using the arrayList to implement next() isn't necessary, but it seemed like the easiest way. If there is a way to do this with the arrayList, that would be preferred. Is this even possible? If not, any advice whatsoever would be welcome! Thanks

Comment: You have an ArrayList holding all the nodes? This is strange if the data structure is supposed to be a binary search tree. Could you edit the question to include more details about what's in this ArrayList, and in what order?

Comment: The ArrayList contains only the leaf nodes, as in this case, the leaf nodes contain all the important data. Then I would like my iterator to be able to iterate through these leaf nodes.

Comment: What does it mean to do an in-order traversal over just the leaf nodes? If only the leaf nodes are processed, then either pre-order, in-order or post-order would process the leaf nodes in the same order. Does the ArrayList happen to contain the nodes in the right order already, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, that was why I made the ArrayList. The arrayList contains the elements in the order in which I wish to iterate them in. So regardless of "in-order", I simply want my next() method to follow the order of my ArrayList

Comment: So you can just write `arrayList.iterator()` to get an iterator, then.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an iterator for the list using iterator() method.

```
        // Create and populate the list 
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); 

        list.add("Hello"); 
        list.add("World");

        // Displaying the list 
        System.out.println("The list is: "+ list); 

        // Create an iterator for the list 
        // using iterator() method 
        Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator(); 

        while (iter.hasNext()) { 
            System.out.print(iter.next() + " "); 
        }
```